# Two Queries : One to get the most recent and one to get the oldest date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, max, min

I think this is an very easy question. I want to get the recent date and the oldest date with a SQL query. The `Datefield` looks like this: `24.04.2019`
If I try to get the recent and oldest date with a `Min` and `Max` function it does not work because it just look at the Day. So 01.01.1800 is younger than 31.03.2019

`TableA` :

```
------------------------------
| A   | B  | C  | Date        |
------------------------------
| 1   | 2  | 3  | 13.02.2017  |
| 2   | 3  | 7  | 15.06.1985  |
| 3   | 3  | 4  | 14.04.2001  |
| 3   | 9  | 8  | 13.01.1789  |
-------------------------------
```

From the above sample data expected result is as below

```
-------------------------------
| Recent Date  | Oldest Date  |
-------------------------------
| 13.02.2017   | 13.01.1789   |
-------------------------------
```

Comment: Help us help you - please share the table's structure and the datatypes. Also, please tag your question with the [tag:rdbms] you are using.

Comment: what do you mean with "most recent and oldest date"? i can't figure it out.
plus: please tag the RDBMS you're using. MySQL, SQL Server,...?

Comment: Recent would my in my example: 13.02.2017 and oldest 13.01.1789. And I am using SQL Management. I hope this information help you a little bit

Comment: Do you want the dates only, or their whole rows?

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store dates as strings, store them using the `date` data type.

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the string to a date type using [`CONVERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT 
    MIN(CONVERT(DATE, column_name, 104)) AS minDate, 
    MAX(CONVERT(DATE, column_name, 104)) AS maxDate
FROM table_name
```

You shouldn't store date values on a column using a string type. Use `DATE` or `DATETIME2` instead.

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1978a0cb51596660d2ddf474d9c8a8bf)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Declare @max varchar(50)
Declare @min varchar(50)
select @min =  min(convert(DATE, date, 104)) from table4
select @max =  max(convert(DATE, date, 104)) from table4
select @max as Recent_Date,@min as Oldest_Date
```